# LINQ-EF Query grouping multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a complex query to do with EF by using LINQ. I know the way to do that with multiple loops manually but I would like to do it with LINQ queries:

Scenario: Test center for students

Database involves in my scenario 5 basic tables: tests, questions, answers, results and participants.

**Tests** contains the tests themselves. (int testId, string testName). 1-N relationship with questions.

**Questions** contains test questions. (int questionID,int testId,string questionText)

**Answers** contains every possible answers for a question: (int answerId,int questionId, bool isCorrect) 1-N relationship with Questions.

**Results** contains a record per every answer, related to the student answering the question: (int ResultId, int AnswerId, int participantId, bool isSelectedByParticipant) 1:1 relationship with Answers.

**Participants**: (int participantId). 1:1 relationship with Results.

I would like to know how many answers did a student respond successfully per every test (so a student can do some exams of course). A question can have one or more answers correct, but always at least one answer correct, so if every answer related with a question is not marked by the student(isSelectedByParticipant = false) the result for that question is wrong.

[image]

Thanks a lot everyone for ur help.

Comment: Not sure about IsSelectedByParticipant attribure of Results entity, as I understand any record that gets into Results will be by a Student (ParticipantId)

Comment: Yes you are right, but by default the Result table is filled with every student attending the exam(before he is attending) marking every results with IsSelectedByParticipant to 'false', so by default an student fails everything unless he mark one answer per question (unfortunately this is business rule not defined by me).

Comment: I know this is not the question, but I'm not sure if you're trying to store a bit too much information. I reckon a result should be a participant's each response (selected answer) to a certain question. In this case you don't need to mark 'IsSelectedByParticipant' as if it's not stored, it's not selected? Just trying to get a grip here.

Comment: yes Army doesnt make sense, but the database design and structure is like that (i didnt create it Im just implementing this specific functionality according to business rules stablished). They are creating every result with everything false before to start and we can not change that, just interpretate it succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to:

```
 results.GroupBy(r => r.ParticipientId).Select(p => new
                {
                    StudentId = p.Key,
                    Count = p.GroupBy(pr => pr.Answer.QuestionId).Select( cc => new {
// any correct answer is not selected or any incorrect answer is selected
                        notCorrect = cc.Any(q => !q.IsSelected && q.Answer.IsAnswerCorrect) || cc.Any(q => q.IsSelected && !q.Answer.IsAnswerCorrect)
                    }).Count(res => !res.notCorrect)
                });
```

Here is working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlR10N)

Comment: **.Count(res => !res.notCorrect)** counts correct answers, because of **!**, so results are ok ;)

Comment: Hello again Marcin J, I've found something new to add to my query, the test Name. Ive been having a look doing another group to retrieve the test name but I wasnt able to find a suitable solution in case of a student is attending more than one test. Thx again 4 ur help

Comment: Now you should group by multiple collumns, something like [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/peJBNl) (its better to group by testid and then select name, but you should figure it out ) ;)